# What is the difference between merging LORA weight with base model and not merging the weight in LLAMA2 (LLM)?

Tags: deep-learning, large-language-model, huggingface, llama, peft

The question is regarding LLM(Large language model). I want to understand it from LLAMA2 perspective.
Can someone explain why the final outcome is almost same without combining weights? Additionally, could you please clarify the process of merging weights and the pros and cons associated with it? I'm curious about both the benefits and drawbacks of merging, as well as the pros and cons of not merging the LORA weight with base model.